# How can I host 2 websites from 1 server? (IIS 6.0)

Tags: iis-6, web-hosting

I have an IIS 6.0 webserver from which I have to host 2 websites. The websites need to be **https** enabled. I am considering the below 2 options.

1. Order 2 virtual IP address for the server and host the website in each IP (Don't know if this is possible)
2. Assign different ports to the websites (say 443, 444)

Can you suggest which is the best alternative among the two above. The sites are relatively light weight and performance is not a consideration. But we need **high availability**.
Also what is the advantage and disadvantage of the 2 options mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Ok,

2: seriously? ;) You mean everyone entering "https" for the site gets the wrong one? For anything public using the stadard ports is basically the ONLY real option.

1: yes, exactly. Possible? Well, do not ask here (noone here knows). Ask you HOST. it is TECHNICALLY possible (heck, I have half a C network on one computer for that), but whether your hoster allows that is another thing. if he does not - change him.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual hosting does not solve the https problem. To have two https sites on the same server you definitely need to have two IP addresses. vs1984 your option 1 is right and option two does not seem to be a good idea.  It not about advantages and disadvantages I think option 1 is the only way of doing it.